# What's the proper way to add s-maxage header when using ResponseCache in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Can anyone please guide what's the proper way to add `s-maxage` header when using `ResponseCache` attribute or `CacheProfile`?

I do see an option of `Duration` but that sets `maxage` I want to set `s-maxage` header.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Response Caching middleware to set `s-maxage`. You can refer to the links below to use this middleware and set its value via **SharedMaxAge**.

[Response Caching Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[OutputCacheParameters.CacheProfile Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.cacheprofile?view=netframework-4.8)